# Changing y axis to percentage in sns.distplot with fit=stats.norm

Tags: python, seaborn

I am plotting a series of gaussian distributions and as I understand it, the y axis is density rather than probability. Is there any way to change this to percentage or probability instead?
My code is as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm    

x = np.random.normal(size=500) * 0.1
ax = plt.figure()
sns.distplot(x, bins=15, kde =False, fit=norm, color='lightseagreen', fit_kws={"color":"lightseagreen"}, hist_kws=dict(alpha=0.7))
```

[image: Gaussian distribution with fit]

Comment: Other than dividing by the sum of x, you mean?

Comment: Have a look at the `hist` argument of `distplot`: `Whether to plot a (normed) histogram`.  Then multiply by 100 for percentages.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, by this then also changes my x axis? Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881175/normed-histogram-y-axis-larger-than-1/61881707#61881707) may help explain why a pdf might contain values larger than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually defining the bins, then plot the histogram, this gives you counts:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm 

x = np.random.normal(size=500) * 0.1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nbins = 20
xlen = np.linspace(-0.4,0.4,nbins)
binwidth = xlen[1] - xlen[0]
sns.distplot(x, bins=xlen, kde =False, color='lightseagreen', 
             fit_kws={"color":"lightseagreen"}, hist_kws=dict(alpha=0.7),ax=ax)
```

[image]

Then fit a normal distribution, obtain the probability inside these bins using the difference of cdf, and then scale down the y-ticks:

```
mu, std = norm.fit(x)
p = np.diff(norm.cdf((xlen-mu)/std))
ax.plot(xlen[:(len(xlen)-1)]+binwidth/2,p*len(x),color='lightseagreen')
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks()/len(x))
```

[image]