# What is the best approach to plot the KDE of an image?

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn, data-science, kernel-density

I am trying to create a kernel density estimation (KDE) plot on a *group* of images to better understand some of the information within the plate/batch that they come from. The specific use-case is to identify, visually, of the optimum threshold value for our thresholding to remove the background within the images.

I've been trying to accomplish this with seaborn's `kdeplot` function.

The below function is what I originally thought should work using the `ravel()` function from numpy.

```py
def getKDE(images):
    ''' get the kernel density estimate (in plot) of a list of images '''
    sns.set(style="darkgrid")
    for index, image in enumerate(images):
        fig = sns.kdeplot(data = image.ravel(), legend=True, color=colors[index-1])
    plt.show()
```

If I run this, with constant `colors = ["r", "b", "g", "c", "m", "y"]`, I get the following plot:

[image: image of kde]

This plot seems like the accurate estimation to me, but I'm not able to understand why the y axis is about 10 times as high as any intensity value of the images (for reference, I am using `skimage.img_as_float` when handling these images). The values show from 0-10, whereas the intensity values are from 0-1. Am I reading this wrong?

Does anyone know if this is the optimal approach in terms of resources (it takes a VERY long time), as well as accuracy? Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding KDE's as well!

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) for an explanation about density. It is normalized such that the total area under the curve is 1. The narrower the range in the x-direction, the higher the y-direction.  See also [Normed histogram y-axis larger than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881175/normed-histogram-y-axis-larger-than-1)

Comment: The main reason why the code could be slow would be dealing with very large images.  Strange things in the code are that `sns.kdeplot()` returns an `ax` but gets stored as `fig` and `index` starting with `0` while using `colors[index-1]`. (Those things don't influence the speed, only the readability and maintainability of the code.) Also, the code seems to suppose that the images aren't full-color, which might or might not be the case.