# How to make the y-axis of a normal distribution reflect probability density

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, normal-distribution, scipy.stats

I am generating normal distributions from the mean and standard deviation of a dataset with this code:

```
sampledRow = dataset.sample()  # Get random item from the dataset
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)  # Create X axis -10 to 10
# Normal Distribution using datas mean and sigma
y = norm.pdf(x, loc=sampledRow['Mean'], scale=sampledRow['Sigma'])

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.vlines(sampledRow['Fitness'], ymin=0, ymax=max(y), linestyles='--')

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Some of my plots appear almost correct (figure 1), but unfortunately most of my plots look like figure 2 in which the y-axis goes far above 1. How can I change the way I handle my data to make the y-axis show probability density (proportion of probability of 100%), while maintaining a normal distribution?

Thank you!

> **Figure 1**
> [image]
>
> Mean = -5.3, Sigma = 0.58

> **Figure 2**
> [image]
>
> Mean = -1.1, Sigma = 0.065

Comment: Well, it is perfectly logical that the probability density function for a narrow sigma gets larger than 1.  The probability density function is normalized such that the total area is equal to one.  See e.g. [Normed histogram y-axis larger than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881175/normed-histogram-y-axis-larger-than-1)

Comment: Oh I see, that makes perfect sense!! I suppose I was thinking of it in the terms of cumulative probability plots so I had it in my head that it should be going to 1. I appreciate the help!!