# Scaling of a Standard Normal Distribution

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution, numpy-random

I have a question that is closely related to this one:

[Normed histogram y-axis larger than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881175/normed-histogram-y-axis-larger-than-1)

The solution of the above thread was to scale the dimensions of the axis properly.
However, that solution was not working for my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import random
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(2023)
a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100000)
sns.histplot(a, bins=np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01), stat='density', color = 'red')
plt.title("Standard Normal Distribution")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('F(x)', rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

The plot for the above code looks like this:

[image: std_normal_dist]

The above image is a standard normal distribution going from -5 to +5 on the x-axis with a step width of 0.01, just like defined by `np.arange()` in the code.

Now I want to modify my code so that I'll get the exact same plot, everything in the same place just like above, but with the x-axis going from -500 to 500 instead of -5 to 5 with a step width of 1 instead of 0.01.

The above solution ([Normed histogram y-axis larger than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881175/normed-histogram-y-axis-larger-than-1)) suggests modifying the value `a`, so that if the dimension in the x-axis gets multiplied by a factor of 100, I'd need to divide the y-axis by a factor of 100. However, modifying my code like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import random
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(2023)
a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100000)
b = a/ 100
sns.histplot(b, bins=np.arange(-500, 500, 1), stat='density', color = 'red')
plt.title("Standard Normal Distribution")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('F(x)', rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

results in a plot like this:

[image: peak_density-function]

First of all is interesting because it raises another question: can something like this be considered a normally distributed function when it has just one possible probability area? So it's like a single square with a total area of 1?

Back to the original issue: How can I modify my code so that the plot will display x values between -500 and 500 with a step width of 1 on the x-axis and have y values in the center (x=0) that are about 0.004?

Comment: If you ask histplot to compute density for you, you would always get ~0.4 in the central bin(s). For N(0,1) there are pretty much no event beyond +-5, so [-500...+500] range won't make a difference. Integral (area) would be 1, and from your first plot you could see you have something at +-4, but 0 beyond, no contribution to integral/area. You could extend bound to +-50 or +-500, there would be no difference

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Yes you are right, it's because of the exponent in the formula. I'm sorry. Do you know if a function could be called normally distributed if it would have a standard deviation and variance of 0? If it would be just one probability area that squares up to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to use `b = a * 100`

Think of it this way:
You generate a random list using normal distribution, with 100,000 elements, with a standard deviation of 1.
If you divide that by 100, you will have a standard deviation of about 0.01.
But with a step of 1, the chance of any numbers falling outside this one bar is effectively 0.
Therefore, you have two options:

1. Divide the step by 100
2. Multiply your data by 100

Comment: Yes I've mixed that up, I'm sorry

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Do you know if a function could be called normally distributed if it would have a standard deviation and variance of 0? If it would be only one single square centered around a point on the x-axis that has an total area of 1?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't. Normal distribution describes the distribution of variables/data points. Given your parameters, there's no variability left. So it's not distributed at all. Additionally, a standard deviation of 0 breaks the math behind normal distribution (division by 0).

But that's not what's happened in your code. You had normal distribution, but the resolution wasn't small enough to show it